# If-statement with && operator checks for 2nd value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, operators

Does an `if-statement` with an `&& operator` check for the second parameter if the first one is `false` / `NO`?

Would the following be able to crash?

```
NSDictionary *someRemoteData = [rawJson valueForKey:@"data"];
if( [someRemoteData isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && someRemoteData.count > 0 ){
    //..do something
}
```

Please no simple yes or no answer, but explain why.

Comment: If Objective-C is like nearly all other languages in this regard, the answer is no it won't, since `&&` shortcuts. Similarly, `||` will stop evaluating when it finds a condition that is true.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it does not evaluate the expression after learning that the answer is going to be `NO`. This is called *short-circuiting*, and it is an essential part of evaluating boolean expressions in C, C++, Objective C, and other languages with similar syntax. The conditions are evaluated left to right, making the evaluation scheme predictable.

The same rule applies to the `||` operator: as soon as the code knows that the value is `YES`, the evaluation stops.

Short-circuiting lets you guard against invalid evaluation in a single composite expression, rather than opting for an `if` statement. For example,

```
if (index >= 0 && index < Length && array[index] == 42)
```

would have resulted in undefined behavior if it were not for short-circuiting. But since the evaluation skips evaluation of `array[index]` when `index` is invalid, the above expression is legal.

Comment: Not to mention that conditions are evaluated in their order of appearances ;) Java has the bizarre-behaving `&` which _does not_ shortcut, too.

Comment: @fge Thanks for the note about the evaluation order, this is very important in the context of this discussion.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I already assumed it did, just wanted to know exactly why.

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C uses [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), which means that only the left operand is evaluated in your case.

Answer (score 0):

NO it does not. If the first statement fails the second is never checked so for example you can do this `(ArrayList != null && ArrayList.size() > 0)` and you will never get an error if the variable is not initialized.